# Look for a particular pattern and do a swap on that line

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a set of files containing

```
    VIEW_NAME FOR COLUMN DNAME      ,
    VIEW_OWNER FOR COLUMN DCREATOR   ,
    OBJECT_NAME FOR COLUMN ONAME      ,
    OBJECT_SCHEMA FOR COLUMN OSCHEMA
```

So, wherever it finds `FOR COLUMN` Keyword it needs to swap the first and last letter in that line. The output should be like

```
   DNAME FOR COLUMN VIEW_NAME,
   DCREATOR FOR COLUMN VIEW_OWNER,
   ONAME FOR COLUMN OBJECT_NAME
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
awk '$2" "$3=="FOR COLUMN"{a=$1; $1=$4; $4=a}1' file
```

- first compare the values if the second (`FOR`) and third field (`COLUMN`)
- if it matches, swap the first (`$1`) and the fourth (`$4`) field

Comment: Hey Chaos, Your command works fine. :) But its not getting reflected to the main file again, if we cat that file, it is not changed, it is in the same old format. What could be the reason?

Comment: @sabarishjackson It's because `awk` doesn't change the file. Use it as follows: `awk ... >tmp_file` and then `mv tmp_file original_file`. With `awk` you cannot edit inplace, so you have to go the way via a temporary file.

Comment: But.

awk '$2" "$3=="FOR COLUMN"{a=$1; $1=$4; $4=a}1' file 

Could you please tell me what is that last 1 for?